# How to check BlockingQueue head element before taking?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I wanna check a head element before taking but raises
`java.lang.NullPointerException` when peeking,

using java BlockingQueue

```
 BlockingQueue sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue()
```

this is my code, any ideas?

```
while(true){
    try {
        if(!sharedQueue.isEmpty()){
            char  ch = (char)sharedQueue.peek();
            if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
                digitTextField.setText(digitTextField.getText()+sharedQueue.take());
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're casting to `char` which doesn't allow nulls. Also, don't do `sharedQueue.isEmpty()` followed by `peek` - that is known as "check-then-act" which is a well-known cause of races.

You should define `sharedQueue` as `BlockingQueue<Character>` then use

`if ((Character c = sharedQueue.poll()) != null)`

Answer (score 1):

[`peek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek%28%29) returns `null` when element not found:

> Returns: the head of this queue, or null if this queue is empty

You need to use:

```
    if(ch != null && Character.isDigit(ch)){
```